# How to set default view of the list as DATAVIEW

Tags: data-view-web-part

I know it should be really easy, but I could not find it anywhere. How to change the existing view to DATAVIEW as default view?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a bit more about what you are using/trying to do, as well as what version of SP you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new view, and select "datasheet view" instead of "standard view". One the next screen check the checkbox for "make this the default view".

Unless you mean something else by "dataview" than the grid-view?